# Shopify custom forms using liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like customers to complete a custom survey so we can gauge which product is most right for them.

My idea is to use a form to collect the customers answers and run a function to determine the product they need.

Is this possible using a shopify theme?

I am very confused on integrating custom logic into a theme

Answer (score 0):

If the logic for the survey is written in Javascript and the function that determines the product is written in Javascript it will be possible.

To be more precise if you don't use the Shopify forms logic, but custom code everything it will be possible but it will require a lot of configuration depending of the survey length.

But things like sending a custom email to the customers or something in those line will not be possible with Shopify (only if you use a third party App for custom forms logic).

Comment: Thanks! So is using JS in liquid okay? or should I avoid it?

Comment: Liquid is the thing that outputs the data and loads before the DOM is read, so you can use Javascript normally as it is a static site after that.